# Parse Parameters of HTTP Get Request

Tags: android, parameter-passing, http-get, http-parameters

A bit of background, I'm creating an SMS Gateway to have the Android phone act as a mini Web Server/SMS Gateway. Whenever a SMS is received, it posts to a web service (external). The web service (external) responds back to the Android's IP Address as a GET request with parameters.

I'm trying to get the parameters of a request made to my android application web service. The object `request` seems to work OK, but I"m having issues parsing through the parameters.

The output of

```
Log.i("WEB_REQUEST", request.getRequestLine().toString());
```

is

```
GET /send.html?smsto=testtes&smsbody=testers HTTP/1.1
```

However, whenever I try to return a specific parameter, it only returns null.

```
        HttpParams params = request.getParams();
        Log.i("WEB_REQUEST", params.getParameter("smsto").toString());
        Log.i("WEB_REQUEST", params.getParameter("smsbody").toString());
```

How can I do something like `String smsto = params.getParameter("smsto").toString();` to return the value of a parameter in the `GET` request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this. It seems strange that the `getParameter` doesn't work. I'm using the exact same variable in this solution, but storing the parameters in a list. I had hoped to not have to use a loop even though this should have minimal impact. Doesn't seem to be that agile.

```
List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(request.getRequestLine().getUri()), HTTP.UTF_8);
for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : parameters) {
  Log.i("WEB_REQUEST", nameValuePair.getName() + ": "+ nameValuePair.getValue());
}
```